# Export a (libgdx) project to jar file with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, libgdx, export

Whenever I try export my game (which works fine in Eclipse) to a runnable JAR file, it will not create a runnable JAR file, just a folder containing the projects data. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I have tried following methods in Eclipse:

> File->Export->Runnable JAR file->Extract required libaries into
>   generated JAR.
>
> File->Export->Runnable JAR file->Package required libaries into
>   generated JAR.

with launch configuration:

> DesktopLauncher - "game"-dektop.

But I just can't get it as a runnable JAR file.

Comment: What do you mean with you just get a folder? It did not create an .jar ?

Comment: Nope, it didn't create a jar-file just a folder with an .jar extension. But I found a solution for it. By zipping the folder and run it in jarsplice turned it into a working runnable file.